# Non-pruned accumulators with asymptotic worst space $O(\log_2 n)$, or cheaper?

Tags: accumulators

The only accumulator that I know is the Merkle tree, which has these asymptotic worst:

- **Space, non-pruned: $O(n)$**.
- Time insertion/removal: $O(\log_2 n)$.
- Time verification: $O(\log_2 n)$.

**My question is:**  Is there any accumulator whose non-pruned version has an asymptotic worst-space that is cheaper than $O(n)$? e.g., perhaps $O(\log_2 n)$?

By non-pruned, I mean not pruned. Pruning is when old entries are ignored by using some new *checkpoint* as the reference.  e.g., since old entries in a Merkle tree don't change, one could delete old entries and use a more recent hash as the new base to verify hashes. I call this *pruning*.  What I want to know is if there is a scalable accumulator that is *not* pruned.

The accumulator does not necessarily need to be ordered. An unordered one is just fine.

Comment: Define "non-pruned." 

Also, when you say "accumulator", do you mean a commitment to an unordered set of elements? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @AlinTomescu updated.

Comment: Constant-sized accumulators (e.g, based on RSA groups or bilinear groups) would satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Thank you @caveman. I am still confused by your terminology to answer your question. When you say "checkpoint" or "reference", you are referring to the digest, correct? e.g., if this were a Merkle tree, you would mean the Merkle root hash, correct?

Comment: @AlinTomescu - Yes, the root hash would be an option, or whatever common node hash two parties agree with.  E.g. if person A and person B agree on some common node's hash, which is not the root, person A can prove to him that his item is in the set by offering a sub-tree of hashes from that links to that node's hash which they commonly agree (even if they don't necessarily agree all the way to the up-to-date root).  I think this can be the basis of some pruning method (deleting nodes that are relate to too-old entries which are no longer getting updated since, say, years).

Comment: @IstvánAndrásSeres - I have to read about it first.  I'd appreciate references/links if you enjoy giving people links :).  Otherwise I'm Duckduckgo-ing it anyway.

Comment: @caveman, for sure, it can be the basis of pruning. This is well understood. Consider a tree of exactly $2^{k+1}$ leaves. If you do not need the first $2^k$ leaves, you can prune their left subtree and end up with just the right subtree of size also $2^k$. Note that in the process you reduced the height from $k+1$ to $k$ which can be helpful. To generalize this, see the notion of "frozen" nodes in _"[CW09] Efficient Data Structures for Tamper-Evident Logging; by Crosby, Scott A. and Wallach, Dan S.; in Proceedings of the 18th Conference on USENIX Security Symposium; 2009"_

Comment: @AlinTomescu - Thanks. I know that part, and this is what I meant by not wanting a solution with pruning.  Because this is an optimisation that benefits ones that have already downloaded the entire transactions and built the Merkle tree from the start.  I'm trying to find a way to optimise it for new comers, so that they don't have to download the whole thing from the start (as it happens with every cryptocurrency today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are correctly using the term "accumulator" to mean a commitment to a set (i.e., unordered) of elements, one simple answer is "no."

There cannot be such an accumulator scheme because, in order to construct membership proofs for *any* element in the accumulated set, one needs to have the full set of $n$ elements which requires $O(n)$ storage.

I cannot point to any paper that proves this, but it seems like a natural result that could be proven.

On the other hand, suppose you do not care about the ability to compute proofs. Perhaps all you care about is keeping the digest up to date as new elements are appended to the accumulator. (e.g., perhaps proofs can be maintained by interesting parties, such as in stateless cryptocurrencies **[RMCI17, CPZ18]**)

Then, many schemes would satisfy your requirement. Some of them are even able to deal with deleting elements.

1. Append-only Merkle trees or forest (e.g., Utreexo **[Dryj19]**)

   - i.e., keep a $O(\log{n})$-sized digest around and you can update it
2. RSA accumulators **[Bd93]**

   - i.e., keep a $O(1)$-sized digest around and you can update it
3. Lattice-based accumulators **[PSTY13]**

   - i.e., keep a $O(1)$-sized digest around and you can update it

Some of these schemes have caveats though: e.g., for RSA accumulators, if you want to update the digest after one or more deletes, you need to additionally have the membership proof(s) for the removed element(s).

## References

[Bd93] One-Way Accumulators: A Decentralized Alternative to Digital Signatures; by Benaloh, Josh and de Mare, Michael; in EUROCRYPT '93; 1994

[CPZ18] Edrax: A Cryptocurrency with Stateless Transaction Validation; by Alexander Chepurnoy and Charalampos Papamanthou and Yupeng Zhang; 2018; https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/968

[Dryj19] Utreexo: A dynamic hash-based accumulator optimized for the Bitcoin UTXO set; by Thaddeus Dryja; 2019; https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/611

[PSTY13] Streaming Authenticated Data Structures; by Papamanthou, Charalampos and Shi, Elaine and Tamassia, Roberto and Yi, Ke; in EUROCRYPT 2013; 2013

[RMCI17] Improving Authenticated Dynamic Dictionaries, with Applications to Cryptocurrencies; by Reyzin, Leonid and Meshkov, Dmitry and Chepurnoy, Alexander and Ivanov, Sasha; in FC'17; 2017

Comment: Care to shed some light on the proof why it is impossible?  I wonder what are the assumptions taken to reach the impossibility.

Comment: I keep running into folks who want a proof for this, including myself :) Let me see if I can write a simple one down and post it here...